# Instead of displaying a ReceiptCard, Skype client returns "Eek! We can't show this card on the version of Skype you have."

Tags: botframework, skypedeveloper

I am returning a ReceiptCard with a Name and List of Fact, but the Skype web client and the desktop app return "Eek! We can't show this card on the version of Skype you have.".  The response ReceiptCard looks fine in the Bot Emulator.

Any ideas on what Skype is not able to show the card?  I have tried the preview versions and also updated Skype, but no luck.  Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: Note that I am not populating all the properties of the ReceiptCard as I only need to return the Facts list - I am using ReceiptCard because it is the only DisplayCard that has a table that I can return to the user.  Here is how I am creating the ReceiptCard, where receiptFacts is a List<Fact> that provides the user the information they requested:  new ReceiptCard("QueryResponseDetails", new List<ReceiptItem>(), receiptFacts, null, null, null, null, cardBtns);

The docs at docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/attachments.html#receiptcard omit what fields are required.

Comment: I found that the BotEmulator crashes unless the name and List<ReceiptItem> are not null.  Does the Skype client have some validation that it does on the ReceiptCard properties?  As I said, I need to use ReceiptCard as it is the only DisplayCard that has a table of facts.

Comment: I confirmed that if I populate the Total, Tax and Vat on the ReceiptCard then the card displays in Skype.  So, I'll have to use another card Type, likely the HeroCard, and format the results in the text field.  This is unfortunate, since I have a list of name value pars to return and the ReceiptCard made that extra simple for me.

I noticed that the ReceiptCard trims facts to 13 chars, which rules out ReceiptCard for me as I have strings that are longer.  The BotEmulator wraps the longer strings to the next line in their column, which I was expecting Skype to do as well.

Comment: One more follow up... HeroCard Text does not support any markdown that can display as a table, and the Text is truncated after about 60 chars.  So, looks like I can't use DisplayCards for what I want to do, which is to return  set of name/value pairs in tabular format.  Unless anyone has a better idea, I'll go back to just using a plain text response until something better is supported.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that at this time Skype does not support tables in cards by sending a key/value pair.